# Does the term of a convergent infinite sum create a convergent infinite product with 1 + term?

Tags: real-analysis

Let
$0<\sum_{n=k}^\infty f(n)<\infty$ where $f(n)>0,n\ge k$.

Then is the following guaranteed to be true:
$$0<\prod_{n=k}^\infty(f(n)+1)<\infty$$
For example:
$$f(n)=\cfrac{1}{n^2}$$ $$\sum_{n=k}^\infty f(n)=\sum_{n=k}^\infty \cfrac{1}{n^2}=\cfrac{\pi^2}{6}$$
$$\prod_{n=k}^\infty(f(n)+1)=\prod_{n=k}^\infty \cfrac{n^2+1}{n^2}\approx 3.676$$
If there is not a guarantee (perhaps shown by a counter-example), then why?

Comment: Use the fact that $\log(x+1) \le x$ whenever $x \ge 0$.

Comment: @UmbertoP. Elaborate on how that applies?

Comment: @user3213847 $\ln \left(\prod_i a_i\right) = \sum_i \ln a_i$.

Comment: @user8268 one of the conditions is that $f(n)>0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's true *(and further the infinite product will be positive)*: suppose you have a *positive* convergent series $\sum_n a_n$. In particular, $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n = 0$, and therefore
$$
\ln(1+a_n) = a_n + o(a_n) \tag{$\dagger$}
$$

Then
$$
\ln \prod_{n=1}^N (1+a_n) = \sum_{n=1}^N \ln(1+a_n)
$$
but the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \ln(1+a_n)$ converges by theorems of comparison for positive series, recalling $(\dagger)$. So 
$$
\lim_{N\to\infty}\prod_{n=1}^N (1+a_n) = \exp\sum_{n=1}^\infty \ln(1+a_n) \in\mathbb{R}_+\,.
$$